# Failed to create provisioning profile for tvOS app

Tags: xcode, tvos

I'm trying to build a tvOS app, but I'm getting the following error:

[image]

Why is a physical device required to build an app? Is there any way to do without it?

I am using Xcode 14, tvOS 16. Automatic signature management is enabled.

Comment: The provisioning profile you're trying to use is a profile that is used to install directly on a pre-determined amount of devices, it won't work for any device. That's why it needs at least one device to be registered.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Thank you so much for your response! It's strange that Xcode is trying to use the provisioning profile for development, because I'm trying to create an assembly for publishing. 'Any tvOS Device' is selected as the target device. I didn't intend to test the app on a real device (because I don't have one). Debugging has already been done on the simulator. So I can't build tvOS apps without having an Apple TV?

Comment: You can, but you need to build using a Distribution certificate, right now you're using a Development one, which only allows you to install on pre-registered devices.

Comment: I tried to use a manually created Distribution certificate, but without success. Thank you once again, anyway.